# how to update data on realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i input data using code like this :

I used calling function:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pegawai");
    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    btn_simpan_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            insertDataPegawai();
        }
    });
```

and my function is like that :
how to make update code? because i already following any code from internet
and it doesn't work.

```
private void insertDataPegawai() {
    boolean valid = true;
    database.child(mUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String nama = ed_nama_lengkap.getText().toString().trim();
            String no_hp = ed_nomor_hp.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = tv_email3.getText().toString().trim();
            String posisi = ed_posisi_user.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
            String tgl_lahir = btn_tanggal_lahir.getText().toString().trim();
            String alamat = ed_alamat_lengkap.getText().toString().trim();
            String jenis_kelamin = ed_jenis_kelamin.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

            if (nama.isEmpty()) {
                ed_nama_lengkap.setError("Nama harus diisi.");
            }
            if (no_hp.isEmpty()) {
                ed_nomor_hp.setError("No Hp harus diisi.");
            }
            if (email.isEmpty()) {
                tv_email3.setError("Email harus diisi.");
            }
            if (alamat.isEmpty()) {
                ed_alamat_lengkap.setError("Alamat harus diisi.");
            } else {

                data_diri data_diri = new data_diri(nama, no_hp, email, posisi, tgl_lahir, alamat, jenis_kelamin);

                database.push().setValue(data_diri);
                Toast.makeText(ProfileSettings.this, "Data Tersimpan!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ed_nama_lengkap.setEnabled(false);
                ed_nomor_hp.setEnabled(false);
                tv_email3.setEnabled(false);
                ed_posisi_user.setEnabled(false);
                btn_tanggal_lahir.setEnabled(false);
                ed_alamat_lengkap.setEnabled(false);
                ed_jenis_kelamin.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Step 1 would be to not ignore errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum it should be: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: As Frank already mentioned in his comment, first of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?